# Dynamically add Items to a QListWIdget

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget

I have this function

```
def search(self):
    
    #creating a list just ignore
    self.listWidget.clear()
    self.gogo.keywordSetter(self.lineEdit.text())
    self.gogo.linkSetter()
    self.gogo.resultsGetter()
    
    #iterarting through the generated lsit
    for x in self.gogo.resultsContainer:
        self.listWidget.update()
        #print(x[2])
        #x[2] is the url to an image
        url = x[2]
        print(url)
        
        req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        webpage = urlopen(req).read()
        
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(webpage)
        icon = QIcon(pixmap)
        #x[1] is a string I want to display it's a title basically
        item = QListWidgetItem(icon, x[1])
        size = QSize()
        size.setHeight(100)
        size.setWidth(400)
        item.setSizeHint(size)
        #item.iconSize(QSize(100, 400))
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
```

It works, my problem is that it displays everything only after it iterates through every item.
What I mean is that I can see it using the print statement that it IS going through the list and creating the items but no items is being displayed.
They get all displayed at once after it completely iterates through the list.
It's very slow. I know part of it is due to the image download and I can do nothing about it. But adding the items dynamically would at least make it a little more bearable.
tried to use update() and it didn't really work.
another weird behaviour is despite the clear() being the first instruction it doesn't clear the listWidget as soon as the function is called, it looks like it's due to the same thing that leads to everything being displayed at one.

Comment: Don't use a for-loop. Retrieve the data with [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) and update the list-widget via [QNetworkReply](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html) signals. That way, the downloads will happen asynchronously and won't block the gui. They will also happen in parallel (up to a maximum of six requests), so the total download time should also be much quicker. (You could also use multi-threading with a queue if you prefer a more DIY approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI systems use an "event loop", which is responsible of "drawing" elements and allow user interaction; that loop must be left free to do its job, and functions that operate within it must return as soon as possible to prevent "freezing" of the UI: the window is not refreshed or properly displayed, and it seems unresponsive to keyboard or mouse events.

Your function does exactly that: it blocks everything until it's finished.
Calling `update()` won't be enough, as it only *schedules* a repainting, which will only happen as soon as the main loop is able to process events. That's why long or possibly infinite for/while loops should always be avoided, as much as any blocking function like `time.sleep`, even for short amounts of time.

> "I can do nothing about it."

Actually, not only you can, but you *have* to.

A possibility is to use threading, specifically [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html), which is an interface that allows to execute calls in a separate thread while providing Qt's signal/slot mechanism that can work asynchronously between thread. Using QThread *and* signals to communicate with the main thread is extremely important, as UI elements are *not* thread-safe, and must ***never*** be accessed (nor created) from external threads.

```
class Downloader(QThread):
    imageDownloaded = pyqtSignal(int, object)
    def __init__(self, parent, urlList):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.urlList = urlList

    def run(self):
        for i, url in enumerate(self.urlList):
            req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
            webpage = urlopen(req).read()
            self.imageDownloaded.emit(i, webpage)


class YourWidget(QWidget):
    # ...
    def search(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()
        self.gogo.keywordSetter(self.lineEdit.text())
        self.gogo.linkSetter()
        self.gogo.resultsGetter()
        
        #iterating through the generated list
        urlList = []
        for x in self.gogo.resultsContainer:
            url = x[2]
            urlList.append(url)
            
            item = QListWidgetItem(x[1])
            item.setSizeHint(QSize(400, 100))
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

        # the parent argument is mandatory, otherwise there won't be any
        # persistent reference to the downloader, and it will be deleted
        # as soon as this function returns; connecting the finished signal
        # to deleteLater will delete the object when it will be completed.
        downloadThread = Downloader(self, urlList)
        downloadThread.imageDownloaded.connect(self.updateImage)
        downloadThread.finished.connect(downloadThread.deleteLater)
        downloadThread.start()

    def updateImage(self, index, data):
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        if not pixmap.loadFromData(data) or index >= self.listWidget.count():
            return
        self.listWidget.item(index).setIcon(QIcon(pixmap))
```

<sup>Note: the code above is untested, as it's not clear what modules you're actually using for downloading, nor what `self.gogo` is.</sup>

A slightly different alternative of the above is to use a persistent "download manager" thread, and *queue* requests using a python `Queue`, which will be read in the `run()` implementation.

---

Consider that Qt provides the QtNetwork module that already works *asynchronously*, and implements the same concept.

You have to create a QNetworkAccessManager instance (one is usually enough for the whole application), then create a QNetworkRequest for each url, and finally call the manager's `get()` with that request, which will return a QNetworkReply that will later be used for retrieving the downloaded data.

In the following example, I'm also setting a custom *property* for the reply, so that when the reply will be received, we will know to what index it corresponds to: this is even more important than what done above, as QNetworkAccessManager can download in parallel, and downloads can be completed in a different order than they were requested (for instance, if the images have different sizes, or are being downloaded from different servers).

Note that the index *must* be set as a Qt property, and cannot (or, better, should not) be set as a python attribute, like `reply.index = i`. This is because the reply we're using in python is just a wrapper around the actual Qt object, and unless we keep a persistent reference to that wrapper (for instance, by adding it to a list), that attribute would be lost.

```
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import *

class YourWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.downloadManager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.downloadManager.finished.connect(self.updateImage)

    # ...
    def search(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()
        self.gogo.keywordSetter(self.lineEdit.text())
        self.gogo.linkSetter()
        self.gogo.resultsGetter()
        
        for i, x in enumerate(self.gogo.resultsContainer):
            item = QListWidgetItem(x[1])
            item.setSizeHint(QSize(400, 100))
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

            url = QUrl(x[2])
            request = QNetworkRequest(url)
            request.setHeader(request.UserAgentHeader, 'Mozilla/5.0')
            reply = self.downloadManager.get(request)
            reply.setProperty('index', i)

    def updateImage(self, reply):
        index = reply.property('index')
        if isinstance(index, int):
            pixmap = QPixmap()
            if pixmap.loadFromData(reply.readAll()):
                item = self.listWidget.item(index)
                if item is not None:
                    item.setIcon(QIcon(pixmap))
        reply.deleteLater()
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.
What you added was also something I wanted to do but didn't how. I've had nightmares about this for the last few days lol

Comment: @IliasOukil you're very welcome. Remember that if an answer solves your issue, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tick mark on its left.

Comment: Was just checking if everything was working properly and it is.
Thanks again, this was so instructive.